# I2C problem sending from Pi to Arduino

Tags: python, i2c, arduino, joystick

i need to send live joystick data from Pygame to my Arduino so arduino can then communicate over serial to my dsm2 module(for RC planes). i wrote code and got it working but had to have a delay this was not suitable for RC plane flight and is not live like i wanted could anyone please help and write an example or fix my code

raspberry pi:

```
import pygame
import time
import smbus
import time
import os

bus = smbus.SMBus(1)

address = 0x07
def writeNumber(v1,v2,v3,v4,v5,v6):
        bus.write_i2c_block_data(address,v1,[v2,v3,v4,v5,v6])
        return -1
def valmap(value, istart, istop, ostart, ostop):
  return ostart + (ostop - ostart) * ((value - istart) / (istop - istart))

pygame.init()

# Set the width and height of the screen [width,height]
size = [1, 1]
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

pygame.display.set_caption("My Game")


# Used to manage how fast the screen updates
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# Initialize the joysticks
pygame.joystick.init()
# -------- Main Program Loop -----------
while True:
    time.sleep(0.2)
    # EVENT PROCESSING STEP
    for event in pygame.event.get():

        # Possible joystick actions: JOYAXISMOTION JOYBALLMOTION JOYBUTTONDOWN JOYBUTTONUP JOYHATMOTION
        if event.type == pygame.JOYBUTTONDOWN:
            print("Joystick button pressed.")
        if event.type == pygame.JOYBUTTONUP:
            print("Joystick button released.")

    joystick_count = pygame.joystick.get_count() 
    # For each joystick:
    for i in range(joystick_count):
        joystick = pygame.joystick.Joystick(i)
        joystick.init()

        # Usually axis run in pairs, up/down for one, and left/right for
        # the other.
        axes = joystick.get_numaxes()
        for i in range( axes ):
            axis = valmap(joystick.get_axis( i ), -1, 1, 0, 200)
            print("Axis {} value: {:>6.3f}".format(i, axis) )

        writeNumber(int(valmap(joystick.get_axis(3), -1, 1, 0, 200)),int(valmap(joystick.get_axis(0), -1, 1, 0, 200)),int(valmap(joystick.get_axis(1), -1, 1, 0, 200)),int(valmap(joystick.get_axis(2), -1, 1, 0, 200)),200,200)


    # Limit to 20 frames per second
    clock.tick(16)

# Close the window and quit.
# If you forget this line, the program will 'hang'
# on exit if running from IDLE.
pygame.quit ()
```

Arduino removed i2c code:

```
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "dsm2_tx.h"

#define BIND_SWITCH  2
#define BIND_LED     3
#define ERROR_LED    5
DSM2_tx tx(6);
int ch0;
int ch1;
int ch2;
int ch3;
int ch4;
int ch5;
int angle = 0;
int newAngle = 0;
const int MaxChars = 4;
char strValue[MaxChars+1];
int index = 0;
/*
 * This is the callback for the bind process--it controls the UI during the bind process
 * Bind completed:  state = 0
 * Bind in progress:  state = 1
 * Bind error:  state = 2
 */
void bind_cb( int state, byte model_id ) {
  if( state == 1 ) {
    digitalWrite(BIND_LED, HIGH);
  }
  else {
    digitalWrite(BIND_LED, LOW);
  }
  if( state == 2 ) {
    digitalWrite(ERROR_LED, HIGH);
  }
}

#define MAX_VAL 200
int reverse(int valuetr, int MIN, int MAX) {
  int reversed_int;
  reversed_int =  (MAX - valuetr) + MIN;
  return reversed_int;
}


void setup() {
  pinMode(BIND_SWITCH, INPUT);
  pinMode(BIND_LED, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ERROR_LED, OUTPUT);

  tx.begin();

  if( digitalRead(BIND_SWITCH) == HIGH ) {
    digitalWrite(ERROR_LED, HIGH);
    tx.bind(bind_cb);
  }
}



void loop() {
  tx.set_channel(0, ch0, MAX_VAL);
  tx.set_channel(1, ch1, MAX_VAL);
  tx.set_channel(2, ch2, MAX_VAL);
  tx.set_channel(3, ch3, MAX_VAL);
  tx.set_channel(4, ch4, MAX_VAL);
  tx.set_channel(5, ch5, MAX_VAL);
  tx.send_frame();
}
```

Comment: i got it to work but it is more reliable if i use my new solution which is to just use the raspberry pi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this first: there is a bug in the i2c hardware of the Raspberry Pi (see [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=146272)). This bug makes communicating with an Arduino unreliable at the default speed... It is wise to test your setup with a much reduced i2c baudrate first.
For me, it worked by adding

```
dtparam=i2c_arm_baudrate=10000
```

to the /boot/config.txt file.

Comment: I was struggling for a few hours at something that should have been easy to resolve. I haven't tested different rates, but this definitely got me on my way. Works on my Uno units, as well as my Trinket Pro units seamlessly.

Answer (score 0):

Your Python has

```py
while True:
    time.sleep(0.2)
```

That means there are at most 5 positional updates per second.

If you change 0.2 to 0.02 you will get up to 50 updates per second which will make your RC device more responsive.

Comment: the arduino cuts out if i send to many bites at once

Comment: That is a failing of the Arduino.  You will have to experiment to find the minimum safe delay at the Pi end.

Answer (score 0):

Ethan,

Can you post the code that didn't work? I'm like to understand what you meant by "cutting out"

I've found that the occasional I2C I/O error is fairly common when communicating between an Rpi and Arduino.  You should ensure that your code has a method of handling what happens when a dropped byte or a missed read occurs.  For example, parse the I2C byte read before sending the value to a servo so you don't drive the servo to an erroneous position on bus error. The I2C bus by default clocks at 100 KHz per this reference
http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/WireLibraryDetailedReference
an occasional "pass" in the code when a read error occurs should't be too noticeable in your system at 100 KHz.